# How to get Service instance using generic asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-6.0

I am working on a console application where I want to get the instance of a generic service type. Here is my implementation it gives me null.

```
 public class HelperService
        {
            private readonly ServiceCollection collection;
            private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
            public HelperService()
            {
                collection = new ServiceCollection();
                serviceProvider = collection.BuildServiceProvider();
            }
            public void RegisterService()
            {
                #region [register Services]
    
                collection.AddScoped<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();
    
                #endregion
    
            }
    
            public T? GetServiceInstance<T>() where T : class
            {
                return serviceProvider.GetService<T>()?? null;
            }
    
        }

var helperService = new HelperService();
helperService.RegisterService();
var result = helperService.GetServiceInstance<ICustomerService>(); // result is null
```

I want to implement generic service to which I will pass any service and it will give instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding service to collection after the `IServiceProvider` was build so it will not know anything about this newly added service, you need to add service before building the provider:

```
    public class HelperService
    {
        private readonly ServiceCollection collection;
        private readonly IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
        public HelperService()
        {
            collection = new ServiceCollection();
            #region [register Services]

            collection.AddScoped<ICustomerService, CustomerService>();

            #endregion
            serviceProvider = collection.BuildServiceProvider();
        }

        public T? GetServiceInstance<T>() where T : class
        {
            return serviceProvider.GetService<T>();
        }
    }
```

Also `?? null` does not make much sense and can be removed.

And in general I would say that such wrapper is not very helpful, at least based on provided code.

Comment: Can you please let me how to register IConfiguration I am facing an issue registering it

Comment: @MuhammadKamran try building configuration as it done for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72341139/2501279) and than adding it to DI. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/configuration) can be helpful.

Comment: I don't have appsetting.json file it is a console application

Comment: @MuhammadKamran you can add it. Or add any other source of configuration (like environment variables and so on) with `Add...` call. What is the source of config for your app?

Comment: I have solve the configuration but now I am facing this error **Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment**

Comment: I am basically building a console application that will use dll from a different application to dump records into the other database

Comment: @MuhammadKamran I would say that you should create an [mre] and post it as a new question.